# Excel chart complex custom number format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have an excel chart that is controlled using slicers. The numbers in the y axis range include negative numbers, positive numbers upto 100+ million dollars. The axis has been formatted to display dollars in millions so if I play with the slicer and the number drops below 10 million, the numbers in the y axis repeat such as $0, $1, $1, $1, $2, $2 etc (in millions).

This is the current custom number format
($* #,##0);($* (#,##0);($* "-"??);(@_)

What I want is something like this:
[<10000000]($* #,##0.0);[>=10000000]($* #,##0);($* (#,##0);($* "-"??);(@_)

As I understand, the above won't work since I cannot apply both conditionals and negative number formats. I cannot apply conditional formatting since it is on a chart axis.

Can this be even done in the first place using this approach? Thank you

Comment: The format you want is not possible as you can only have three different number formats, and you are showing four. If you cannot reduce this to three, there will not be a solution that involves number formatting.  And it would be more helpful if you showed the actual vs desired-display rather than non-functioning numberformat codes.

Comment: SInce you have not shared sample data with us so it's difficult to try what I'm suppose to but you may try this `[>999999] #,,"M";#,"K"` will display `K` for thousand to `900K` to `Million` or even this one works, `#,, "Million"` ! Second one works for Millions only.